# Server-side authorization with JWT in SvelteKit

Tags: sveltekit

I have an issue sending a JWT token to the server and using it to authorize access in `load` handlers. I am using Firebase on the client for authentication. When logged in (`onAuthStateChanged`), I send a `POST` request with the token to the `/api/login` endpoint:

```
  export async function post(req) {    
    const idToken = req.headers['authorization']
    try {
        const token = await firebase().auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
        req.locals.user = token.uid
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        return {
            status: 500,
            body: 'forbidden',
        }
    }
    
    return {
        status: 200,
        body: 'ok',
    }
}
```

In `hooks.js`:

```
export function getSession(request) {
    return {
        user: request.locals.user
    }
}

export async function handle({ request, resolve }) {
    const cookies = cookie.parse(request.headers.cookie || '')
    request.locals.user = cookies.user

    const response = await resolve(request)

    response.headers['set-cookie'] = `user=${request.locals.user || ''}; Path=/; HttpOnly`

    return response
}
```

In `load` methods:

```
export async function load({ session }) {
   if (!session.user) {
      return {
         status: 302,
         redirect: '/start'
      }
   }

   // ...
}
```

All of this works fine except that any client-side navigation after a login is rejected because `session.user` is still undefined. When navigating by typing the URL in the browser, it works correctly and after that the client-side navigation also works.

Any ideas why and what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by adding a browser reload on whichever page the user lands on after logging in. The snippet for the reload on the client side handling on a successful response from the login API endpoint looks like this

```js
if (sessionLoginResponse?.status === "success") {
            await signOut(auth);
            window.history.back();

            setTimeout(() => {
              window.location.reload();
            }, 10);
          }
```

Comment: Why `signOut`? I don't get it. I tried the reload approach which caused a loop of reloads because `onAuthStateChanged` fired again. Then I introduced a different response from the endpoint if the user was already logged in and only did the reload if not. That seemed to work at first but I've seen it happen again since then.

Comment: So, with firebase auth, you're storing a session cookie in your JWT and verifying that on each request. You can follow the documentation over [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies#sign_in). This approach works better in my experience that fighting with access tokens and refresh tokens which work better in a SPA situation in my experience

Comment: Still confused. This causes `onAuthStateChanged` with `null` being called on the client, so I'm effectively logged out on the client. Did I do something wrong? I want to stay logged in on the client as well.

Comment: In a SSR app, ideally, once you have your backend provide your client app with their JWT, you are able to logout and make subsequent requests to your backend by including the JWT in a cookie. And in that case you dont need to listen for auth state change as your JWT is validated on every request to the server. Reason you need the client logged in?

Comment: Because the client also uses Firebase directly. I have a mixture of prerendered routes with some client-side Firebase code and server-renderered routes.

Comment: Got it. In that case you can't logout. You have to maintain both auth states. For SSR, you'll use the JWT token stored in your cookie to make requests to your backend and firebase admin can serve up data that way.
For client side, you'll have to listen for auth state changes using the Firebase JS SDK and handle updating UI according

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first we need to separate the two firebase SDKs (admin/firebase aka client).
My complete solution is very similar to what you are trying to do with one subtle difference.
Here I leave my explanation with a little code.

1. Call on client side your auth method using firebase/auth and get the authTokenId.
2. Send the token to your /api/login in the body and store it using the cookies like:

```js
default: async ({ request, cookies, url }) => {
....
cookies.set('token', token, { httpOnly: true, secure: true, path: '/' });

return { success: true }
```

3. After you set the cookies (in server side) you can redirect the user to the home page.

And here comes the tricky part, within your server hooks, you can verify that the cookie you saved is a valid token id. This is where the firebase-admin lib comes in which will allow you to validate the token and get user information.

1. Get the user information on every call to the server (hooks.server.ts)

```js
const token = event.cookies.get('token')
const decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifySessionCookie(token, true)
// do a auth check if the decodedToken is invalid redirect the user to the login page

// if the decodedToken is valid, you can store it in the locals.
if (decodedToken) {
        event.locals.user = {
            uid: decodedToken.uid,
            email: decodedToken.email,
            avatar: decodedToken.picture,
            displayName: ''
        };
    }
```

2. Now you will be able to obtain user information in all your SSR load functions `(+{page,layout}.server.ts)` like:

```js
export const load = async ({ locals }) => {
    const user = locals.user;

    return { user };
};
```

Some caveats:

1. never call firebase-admin in client side.
2. to use firebase-admin you will need to do extra config.
3. secure your token using `{ httpOnly: true, secure: true }` config, but be aware that they cannot be accessed on the client side using the cookie api.

I hope it is useful to you, regards.